# Excel - Comparing two columns and extracting data from one into another

Tags: microsoft-excel

I need help with  an excel formula for a project I'm doing. I can't find the one that I need.

I have 2 lists of data in different tabs in Excel (Tab 1 and Tab 2). Both Tab 1 and 2 have a column with ID numbers. Tab 2 has information that I need to feed into Tab 1, but only if the ID numbers match.

I would need a formula that compares  ID from Tab 2 to ID from Tab 1 and then if they are equal or present then it copies the value from column A in Tab 2 into column A of Tab 1.

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `ID` is in column `B` in both sheets, the formula for cell `'Tab 1'!A2` would be:

```
=INDEX('Tab 2'!A:A,MATCH(B2,'Tab 2'!B:B,0))
```